# How to write a Dataset to Kafka topic?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.1.0 and Kafka 0.9.0.

I am trying to push the output of a batch spark job to kafka. The job is supposed to run every hour but not as streaming.

While looking for an answer on the net I could only find kafka integration with Spark streaming and nothing about the integration with the batch job.

Does anyone know if such thing is feasible ?

Thanks

UPDATE :

As mentioned by user8371915, I tried to follow what was done in [Writing the output of Batch Queries to Kafka](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-the-output-of-batch-queries-to-kafka).

I used a spark shell :

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0
```

Here is the simple code that I tried :

```
val df = Seq(("Rey", "23"), ("John", "44")).toDF("key", "value")
val newdf = df.select(to_json(struct(df.columns.map(column):_*)).alias("value"))
newdf.write.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("topic", "alerts").save()
```

But I get the error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider does not allow create table as select.
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:215)
... 50 elided
```

Have any idea what is this related to ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

**tl;dr** You use outdated Spark version. Writes are enabled in 2.2 and later.

Out-of-the-box you can use Kafka SQL connector (the same as used with Structured Streaming). Include

- `spark-sql-kafka` in your dependencies.
- Convert data to `DataFrame` containing at least `value` column of type `StringType` or `BinaryType`.
- Write data to Kafka:

  ```
  df   
    .write
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", server)
    .save()
  ```

Follow [Structured Streaming docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) for details (starting with [Writing the output of Batch Queries to Kafka](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-the-output-of-batch-queries-to-kafka)).

Answer (score 5):

If you have a dataframe and you want to write it to a kafka topic, you need to convert columns first to a "value" column that contains data in a json format. In scala it is

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val kafkaServer: String = "localhost:9092"
val topicSampleName: String = "kafkatopic"

df.select(to_json(struct("*")).as("value"))
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaServer)
  .option("topic", topicSampleName)
  .save()
```

Comment: This is the answer that I am looking for. How to convert data frame consisting multiple columns to a dataframe consisting one column named "value". Thanks

Comment: when i run this command on spark shell, local laptop the code hangs for ever. any idea?

Comment: Yes it does hang. You better try df2=df.cahce() ; df2.show() ; and then replace the above command from df to df2; this will speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

For this error
**java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider does not allow create table as select.
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)**

I think you need to parse the message to Key value pair. Your dataframe should have value column.

Let say if you have a dataframe with student_id, scores.

```
df.show()
>> student_id | scores
    1         |  99.00
    2         |  98.00
```

then you should modify your dataframe to

```
value
{"student_id":1,"score":99.00}
{"student_id":2,"score":98.00}
```

To convert you can use similar code like this

```
df.select(to_json(struct($"student_id",$"score")).alias("value"))
```