# Writing to Kafka topic from Scala Spark fails with error: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read data from Elasticsearch and dump the data into Kafka topic. When writing to Kafka topic I get `ClassCastException`

I am using Spark 2.3.2 and Scala 2.11.2. I am running the below code and ending up in `ClassCastException`. I am not sure how to fix this. The same code (writing to Kafka from Spark) seems to be working for others (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66546024/153271).

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import spark.implicits._


val reader = spark.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.nodes.wan.only","false").option("es.port","9200").option("es.net.ssl","false").option("es.nodes", "elasticsearch.com").option("es.read.field.include","userId,refNum").option("es.nodes.discovery","true")
val df = reader.load("xxxxx")
df.show()

df.registerTempTable("dftable")
val df2=sql("select * from dftable where refNum='yyyy' limit 2 ")
df2.show

 val kafkaServer: String = "localhost:9092"
 val topicSampleName: String = "quickstart-events"
 df3=df2.cache()

df3.select(to_json(struct("*")).as("value")).selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").write.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaServer).option("topic", topicSampleName).save()
```

The error I get is as follows

```
2022-05-02 14:02:52 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 19.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 19.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 19.0 (TID 27, 192.168.22.145, executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1 to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.cleanF$6 of type scala.Function1 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2301)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2411)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1651)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1639)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1872)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1821)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1810)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:933)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:933)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.write(KafkaWriter.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createRelation(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:206)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:264)
  ... 51 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$$anonfun$write$1 to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.cleanF$6 of type scala.Function1 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29
  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2301)
  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1431)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2411)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is what I have tried so far:

1. When I run the code `df3.select(to_json(struct("*")).as("value")).selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")` I get the below result
2. and when I run this code I get to see the json in the dataframe `df3.select(to_json(struct("*")).as("value")).selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").show`. Meaning somewhere in `.write.format("kafka")` is where the issue is coming. I am unable to identify it.

I am new to Spark/Scala. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like deserialization error.
You might want to check weather you have properly structured data for Kafka.

Seems like this part holds error:

```
struct("*")).as("value"))
```

Check [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-streaming-queries) to check how to create Kafka Source for Streaming Queries.